# CSS style quotes and their content

Tags: css

I want to highlight quotes and if possible their contents. Main purpose would be to see easily if they are matching or unbalanced.

```
 This is a "test" with a "quick fox jumping" with unbalanced "quotation
```

I know that their exists the `<q>` tag. Unfortunately I cannot use this tag since the text is edited directly.

To my understanding there is `[attribute=value]` selector. But since I don't wanna limit it to a specific tag I have no clue how to use it there. Next I thought about the pseudo elements `odd` and `even` but here I'm not sure if I can use them with the attribute selector. And last but not least how to highlight the `content` (diffently from the quotes themself)? Since I'm not clear how to combine them.

Comment: This question requires more information. So you want to select any text that's within quotes? Can you use Javascript? The `[attribute=value]` applies to attributes of an element like `href` or `data-value` - not content, since CSS is not content aware.

Comment: Ahhh... Well JavaScript might be an option... The link from Tad looks promising.